# PHPMailer sending duplicate emails to some email addresses

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm facing an issue with PHPMailer, I sent emails to 6 email addresses, 2 of them received the message twice.

The hosting is Godaddy and I'm using the latest version of PHPMailer.

Here is the code:

```
//Including PHPMailer files
require_once('phpmailer/src/phpmailer.php');
require_once('phpmailer/src/SMTP.php');
require_once('phpmailer/src/Exception.php');

$msg = '';

//List of email adressess
$recipients = array('help@example.com', 'user@example.com', 'desk@example.com', 'admin@example.com', 'contact@example.com', 'schedule@example.com');

//Initializing PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      
    $mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;                               

    //Sender data
    $mail->setFrom('info@example.com', 'Info');
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Info');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Hello World!';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hello World!';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Hello World!';

    //Loop throught the email addresses
    foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {

        $mail->addAddress($recipient);

        //Attachments
        $mail->AddStringAttachment($pdfString, $filename); 

        //Check if the message was sent
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $recipient) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
            break; //Abandon sending
        } else {
            echo "Message sent to :"  . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $recipient) . ')<br />';
        }

        // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
        $mail->clearAddresses();
        $mail->clearAttachments();
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Both 'user@example.com' and 'contact@example.com', The 2nd and the 5th received the message twice.

The script was executed once and I use `$mail->clearAddresses();` to clear the email addresses before the next loop.

What's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: is it always the same users? what if you tried switching the order in the array?

Comment: @coderodour, I didn't try, But I will do now

Comment: Your structure all looks correct, and your config looks correct for GoDaddy, so well done on that. If you set `SMTPDebug = 2` you will be able to see exactly what messages are being sent and who to (look out for `RCPT TO` SMTP commands in the stream). If they are all correct but you're still seeing duplicates, it's not your code doing it.